# Get files for a given package

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg

After installing `torguard` it creates a folder in the following path:
`~/.local/share/VPNetworkLLC/TorGuard` (apart from other folders)

When I try to get the files for the package I use:

`dpkg-query -L torguard`

I get many files and folders, but not that one I am talking about (`~/.local/share/VPNetworkLLC/TorGuard`).

I have also tried `dpkg-deb -c <package.deb>` but still can't get that folder.

I am not sure if that is because the folder is hidden or something and can't figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Packages don't track the files that packaged software creates in a user's home directory, so it's perfectly normal that neither `dpkg-query` nor `dpkg-deb` know about that particular folder.